# Passing in integer parameter to AWS StepFunction causes Invalid State Machine Definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-step-functions, aws-serverless

I’m defining a waiting type step function with the serverless framework stack that takes a variable as its timeout setting, like so:

```
WaitForReview:
  Type: Task
  TimeoutSeconds: $.submission.duration
  Resource: 'arn:aws:states:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:activity:${self:service}-${opt:stage}-activity_waitForReview'
  Next: HowToProceed
  ResultPath: '$.submission'
  Catch:
    - ErrorEquals:
        - States.Timeout
      ResultPath: '$.error'
      Next: CreditArtistAccount
```

The one that matters here is `$.submission.duration`. It’s supposed to be an integer, but when I try to deploy my stack I get the follow error:

```
Invalid State Machine Definition: 'SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED: Expected value of type Integer at /States/WaitForReview/TimeoutSeconds' (Service: AWSStepFunctions; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidDefinition; Request ID: bb1a13c2-12cb-11e9-b1f0-4f37f70268ef)
```

Does anyone know how I can grab a variable from the stack and pass it in to the step function and have it be an integer when I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State `Task` field TimeoutSeconds must be a positive, non-zero integer as defined in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-task-state.html). You cannot use state path to define the TimeoutSeconds. If set, generally it is likely to be identical to the resource function timeout.

Comment: I understand that it has to be an integer but that value, $.submission.duration, is an integer, hence why I don't understand this error. I'm actually looking for a way for that value to be output properly as the integer it is.

Comment: $.submission.duration may be an integer but TimeoutSeconds cannot be defined using the state path. I also needed that but unfortunately as of now step functions do not support state path for TimeoutSeconds field.

Comment: So there's no way to handle this current use case?

Comment: No. You need to specify maximum time allowed for an activity worker or a lambda to return response. It cannot be dynamic.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the lambda to return response? Thanks for the help.

Comment: If resource is a lambda then it should be fine because it will always return response if timeout but for activity worker you should define timeout as suggested in the best practices. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-stuck-execution.html